# Force close (duplicate fragment) when recreateView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I follow the tutorial here [Android Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

and in The `ArtistFragment.class`

```
public class ArtistFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        return fragView;
    }
}
```

At First I select Tab `Artist` it show view but, when I switch to another tab, then, switch back  to `Artist` Tab again, It cause force close.

`main_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/frags" >

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.android.custom.FragmentLeft"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_left"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <fragment 
        android:name="com.android.custom.FragmentRight"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_right"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at com.android.custom.ArtistFragment.onCreateView(ArtistFragment.java:20)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:776)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1133)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:628)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1309)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:398)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f080011, tag null, or parent id 0x7f080010 with another fragment for com.android.custom.FragmentLeft
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4182)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
05-27 11:58:36.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4216):     ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does `R.layout.main_fragment` have two fragments inside of it? A `Fragment` cannot have another `Fragment` inside of it...it must be inside an `Activity`. Is there an `artist_fragment.xml` that you meant to inflate instead?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in the `onCreate` method in

```
if(savesInstanceState == null) {
    // your code here
}
```

This will prevent the framework from trying to recreate everything on an orientation or activity change (which is what I think is happening).  You should (in most cases) have this in every activity so the framework can function like most people expect it to.